# Proper HTTP GET Request

Tags: java, html, http, get, httprequest

I am having some difficulty understanding the concept of an HTTP GET Request, besides the fact that I know it asks to read a web page from a server. Today I wrote a class that tries to use a HTTP GET Request in order to gain access to the html material on the webpage. Let me include the class and explain my confusion:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HTMLFetcher 
{
    private static final int PORT = 80;
    private URL url;


    public HTMLFetcher(String url) throws Exception // url = http://www.-----.com/birds.html
    {
        this.url = new URL(url);
        fetch(this.url.getHost());
    }

    private  String createRequest(URL url) { // Is there a problem with this request? 
        String request = "GET" + "/index.html" + "HTTP/1.1\n";
        request += "Host: www.cs.usfca.edu\n";
        request += "Connection: close";
        request += "\r\n";
        return request;
        }

    public void fetch(String urlDomain) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(urlDomain + ":" + PORT);

        // TODO: create a new socket here for a given urlDomain and a given PORT
        Socket socket = new Socket(urlDomain, PORT);

        // TODO: create PrintWriter for the socket's output stream
        PrintWriter writer = 
                new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

        BufferedReader reader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String request = createRequest(urlDomain); // createRequest is complaining       that it is a string and not a URL 
        System.out.println(request);
        writer.write(request);
        writer.flush();

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        boolean htmlFound = false;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!htmlFound) {
                if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("<html>")) {
                    htmlFound = true;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("This is each line: " + line);
            string.append(line + "\n");
        }

        reader.close();
        writer.close();
        socket.close();

        //System.out.println(string.toString());
        System.out.println("[done]");
    }
    }
```

So basically I am confused as to how I can send a String urlDomain into the createRequest method when it is expecting a URL? Is the createMethod parameter necessary for the HTTP Request? Am I setting up the request properly?

Right now it is outputting the following:

```
www.cs.usfca.edu:80
GET/index.htmlHTTP/1.1
Host: www.cs.usfca.edu
Connection: close

This is each line: <html><head>
This is each line: <title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
This is each line: </head><body>
This is each line: <h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
This is each line: <p>GET/index.htmlHTTP/1.1 to /index.html not supported.<br />
This is each line: </p>
This is each line: <hr>
This is each line: <address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.cs.usfca.edu Port 80</address>
This is each line: </body></html>
[done]
```

Thank you for your help. Please let me know if I can be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use  HttpURLConnection http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the host header in the request is used when the website is on a shared hosting server, where multiple domains will be mapped to same ip and the server need the `Host` header to identify the virtual server to which the request to be routed. So its always better to include that in the request.

BTW, in the current code, there is no spaces in the request string. That's why you are getting the error html as response.

```
private String createRequest(String url) { // Is there a problem with this request? 
    String request = "GET " + "/ " + "HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request += "Host: www.cs.usfca.edu\n";
    request += "\r\n";
    return request;
}
```

Also, don't check like this

```
if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("<html>"))
```

Instead use

```
if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("<html"))
```

BTW, why do you have to do it the hard way? Go for HTTPUrlConnection instead.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I thought I had that taken care of. For some reason, it is outputting a different message now: This is each line: <html><head>
This is each line: <title>400 Bad Request</title>
This is each line: </head><body>
This is each line: <h1>Bad Request</h1>
This is each line: <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
This is each line: </p>
This is each line: <hr>
This is each line: <address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.cs.usfca.edu Port 80</address>
This is each line: </body></html>
[done]

Comment: This might be helpful http://code.joejag.com/2012/how-to-send-a-raw-http-request-via-java/